# ¿Cómo puedo obtener todos los ficheros que contiene un repositorio con la API de GitLab?

Tags: rest, gitlab

Tengo un repositorio en GitLab sobre el cual quiero consultar todos los ficheros que tiene mediante una llamada SOAP.

Todos estos ficheros están dentro de la raiz, es decir, no están almacenados dentro de otro directorio.

Estoy ejecutando la siguiente llamada REST:

```
http://Git_Server:19090/api/v4/projects/205/repository/files/%2E?ref=master
```

donde `%2E` es el punto, pero me aparece el mensaje:

```
{"message": "404 File Not Found"}
```

Si pongo un `.` en vez de `%2E` me aparece el mismo mensaje:

```
{"message": "404 File Not Found"}
```

En ese repositorio, directorio raíz, sé que existe un fichero llamado "aaa".

Si ejecuto la siguiente llamada rest

```
http://Git_Server:19090//api/v4/projects/205/repository/files/aaa?ref=master
```

Me devuelve los datos correctamente:

```
{
   "file_name": "aaa",
   "file_path": "aaa",
   "size": 0,
   "encoding": "base64",
   "content": "",
   "ref": "master",
   "blob_id": "e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391",
   "commit_id": "6d7dc7ff1e5a7fc554ad15bb6d2c08277a3b0594",
   "last_commit_id": "9b85518da1f503cd99209cec85122a93379e93c5"
}
```

¿Sabría alguien cómo tendría que generar la llamada para que me devuelva los ficheros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que marcas `.` porque con ello estarías indicando el directorio base. Sin embargo, la API de GitLab tiene otra forma de mostrar todos los ficheros en un directorio, y es la de indicar `/tree`, tal y como se explica en [List repository tree](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#list-repository-tree) de la documentación oficial:

```
/api/v4/projects/:id/repository/tree
```

Si quieres ver la estructura recursivamente, añade el parámetro `recursive=1`:

```
/api/v4/projects/:id/repository/tree?recursive=1
```

En tu caso particular:

```
http://Git_Server:19090/api/v4/projects/205/repository/tree?recursive=1
```